# How can I select multiple values in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, fetch-api

I am trying to select multiple value from from select field, but I can only select one field and I fetch data from API and in API endpoint I can select multiple user like `user=1,2,3` and I also want to select multiple user in react js. Here is my code:

This is my form:

```
 <select
      multiple={true}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      value={this.state.selectedOptions}
      className="form-control btn-block"
      id="exampleFormControlSelect2 btn-block"
      style={{
        width: "200px",
        color: "rgba(19, 183, 96, 1.0)"
      }}
      name="idd"
    >
      {this.state.movies.map(c => (
        <option value={c.pk}>{c.user1}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
```

Here is handle change event and fetch data:

```
handleChange(event) {
    //this.setState({value: event.option});
    this.setState({
      value: Array.from(event.target.selectedOptions, item => item.value)
    });
  }

  // Get Data From Backend
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(config.apiUrl.reportModel);
      const movies = await res.json();
      // console.log(report);
      this.setState({
        movies
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Please help. I'm stuck here and I don't know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your select field props change `value={this.state.selectedOptions}` to `value={this.state.value}`

working (simplified) snippet

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
    state={
        value:null,
        movies:[{user1:'iRobot', pk:'1'},{user1:'Matrix', pk:'2'},{user1:'Hackers' , pk:'3'}]
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
             value : Array.from(event.target.selectedOptions, item => item.value)
        });
    }
    
    
    render(){
    return (
        <select
            multiple
            onChange={(e)=>console.log()}
            value={this.state.value}
        >
            {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
                <option value={movie.pk}>{movie.user1}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
    )
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(
    <SomeComponent />,
    document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id='react'></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library react-select which you can use to achieve the desired functionality. Following is the link to official npm site for that package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select